# Conditions for extending a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, limits

Is the following true? Can you help me proving it?

Let $f,g$ be two smooth functions $J \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $J$ is some interval. Let $t_{0}$ denote an isolated point in the zero set $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ of $f$, i.e. a point in $J$ such that $f(t_{0}) = 0$ and there exists a neighbourhood of $t_{0}$ containing no other zero of $f$.

Statement 1. If the function $h = \frac{g}{f}$ is bounded, then
$$\lim_{t \to t_{0}^{-}} h(t) = \lim_{t \to t_{0}^{+}} h(t).$$

Statement 2. If the function $h = \frac{g}{f}$ is bounded, then
$$\lim_{t \to t_{0}^{-}} h'(t) = \lim_{t \to t_{0}^{+}} h'(t).$$

Comment: If $f$ has a zero of finite order at $t_0$, it's true. But it's not true for all smooth $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are wrong. Consider the function 
$$
 f \colon \def\R{\mathbf R}\R \to \R, x \mapsto \begin{cases} \exp(-x^{-2}) & x \ne 0 \\ 0 & x = 0\end{cases} 
$$
Then $f \in C^\infty(\R)$ with $f^{-1}(0) = 0$. Define $h \colon \R \to \R$ by 
$$ 
  h(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \ge 0\\ 23 & x < 0 \end{cases} 
$$
Then $g := fh \in C^{\infty}(\R)$, $h = \frac gf$ is bounded, but its limits at $t_0 = 0$ do not agree.

In the same line of thought, a counterexample to the second claim is given with 
$$ h(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \ge 0\\ 23 x & x < 0\end{cases} $$
and again $g = fh$.

Comment: I think your first function should be called f

Comment: Here all derivatives of $f$ at $t_{0}$ vanish, i.e. $f$ is flat at $t_{0}$. Do you think the statement would be true if one requested $t_{0}$ not to be flat?

Comment: Yes, it $f$ has finite order at $t_0$, the statement should hold.